# Read tar files and ignore zeros support in archive/tar standard library?

Tags: go, tar, archive

in tar [specification](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=5), a normal tar file should end with consecutive zeros. The archive/tar standard library in Go does very well on reading the tar file.

However, unlike command line tool `tar`, which supports the option `-i` for ignoring zeros, the archive/tar does not support this feature. This could be easily created by concatenating two `.tar.xz` files, and the concatenated .xz file is a valid 2 stream .xz file.

Is there some workaround that the archive/tar can handle such tar files? Great thanks.

I have tried using the [xz library](https://github.com/ulikunitz/xz), suppling the xz reader to the tar reader. The tar reader can iterate the `.tar.xz` in the first stream, but ignores the following stream.

I have sent a [PR](https://github.com/ulikunitz/xz/pull/54) for adding the ability to separate different streams, and supply the stream to a tar reader respectively. I am curious is there a workaround to perform the similar feature as `-i` to ignore zeros in the command line tool `tar`.

Comment: Have you tried creating a second tar.Reader with the same xz reader after the first tar reader is done?

Comment: No luck, I tried supplying the same `bytes.Buffer`, initiate second tar reader reading from it after first tar reader read til end, but still getting `io.EOF`.